# Creating a Tableau Parameters Across Sources with Different Values

Tags: parameters, tableau-desktop

I am creating a parameter in tableau to filter across two data sources (for an urban planning class) in a dashboard but ran into a problem. In one source, the column is Homeless and the values are Y or N but in the other source the values are Y or N/A. Well when I try to create a calculated field after creating the parameter to do parameter=dimension and then drag to the filters table, I only get False conditions, it won't add. How do I create a parameter when the outputs for Y/N are different in each source? Is there an easy way around this? If I try to change N/A and N to both display as Y, Tableau's parameter creation window says each input needs a unique output.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, used a calculated field to change the N/A values to N with

```
if [Foster Y/N]='Y' then "Y" else "N"
```